# Scala :Returning a Function with variable argument from another function

Tags: scala, variadic-functions

My requirement is to return a function from another function in scala which takes variable argument i.e while executing the returned function , i can pass multiple argument at runtime.

My code looks like :

```
object VarArgTest {
  def getFunction(): (Map[String, String],Map[String, Any]*) => Any={
    (arg:Map[String,String], arg2:Map[String,Any]*) => "random"//this gives compilation error
  }
}
```

In code , i want to return a function which take , Map[String,String] as one argument ,while the other Map[String,Any] should be optional to it.

But i get compilation error in return statement as follow:

```
type mismatch; found : (Map[String,String], Map[String,Any]) required: (Map[String,String], Map[String,Any]*) ⇒ Any
```

Can anyone help , what have i missed here?
Note: My requirement is that returned function can take either one argument `(Map[String,String])` or it can take two arguments max `(Map[String,String], Map[String,Any])`

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to use varargs in anonymous function.
You can get your piece of code working by making the returned function nested instead of anonymous like this:

```
object VarArgTest {
  def getFunction(): (Map[String, String],Map[String, Any]*) => Any = {
    def nestedFunction(arg:Map[String,String], arg2:Map[String,Any]*) = "random"
    nestedFunction
  }
}
```

However since you don't need multiple instances of `Map[String, Any]` but either none or one, you would be better off using `Option[Map[String, Any]]`, providing `None` when it is not needed.